# How can I connect android app to arduino via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-application

I’m doing a sign language glove project and wanted to send the data from arduino to the mobile application via Bluetooth. I’m hoping someone could help me and explains how can i achieve that , all i can find is examples on temperature , humidity and a led turning on and off .

Comment: Have you considered using espruino instead of ardruino? With espruino you'd be writing code in javascript instead of c. https://www.espruino.com/Quick+Start+BLE

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.